# Plot ages in a histogram using birthdays

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and I would like to plot the ages of these people on a histogram
(or plot). I have a data frame with birthdays like this:

```
a=c("08.11.1979","17.03.1990","19.08.1990","20.06.1986","13.02.1980")

data.frame(a)

      a
1 08.11.1979
2 17.03.1990
3 19.08.1990
4 20.06.1986
5 13.02.1980
```

How can I convert this column into the default data format and plot the age of each row on in histogram?

I would like to see if the distribution is normal.This is just a small reproducible example, I have a much bigger column than this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this to start:

```
a=c("08.11.1979","17.03.1990","19.08.1990","20.06.1986","13.02.1980")
A=data.frame(DOB=as.Date(a,format='%d.%m.%Y'))
A$AGE=as.numeric(as.Date(Sys.time())-A$DOB)/365
hist(A$AGE)
```

You will plot the age in years, looking like this:
[image: Histogram]

Is this on the right direction?

Comment: Maybe add the plot itself too

Comment: @DavidArenburg added. You are right, I should have done that in the original reply. Thank you.

Comment: @Nikos

Thanks a lot!